# Ember data: save loses belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following problem:

A form with a select field for selecting the category of a post.  Let's say the post has category 100.  In Ember inspector, this is shown as follows:

```
category: <App.Category:ember708:100>
```

When I save the post (via Ember Data 1.0.0 beta 2), the category suddenly changes to:

```
category: 100
```

And the value is no longer selected in the select list.  It is cleared.

Code to save:

```
    post.save().then(
            function () {
              alert("Save OK");
            }
    )
```

Any idea in which direction I need to search ...  If I transition to another page and then go back to the edit screen, the values are all correct. The data is thus still correct in the model ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the latest canary [build](http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.js), this will fix the `belongsTo` issue, but for `hasMany` I tried modifying the code of ember-data, and it worked so far,

Changed the line no 167 to

```
if (relationshipType === 'manyToNone' 
 || relationshipType === 'manyToMany' 
 || relationshipType === 'manyToOne')
```

**Update**

Better solution is override `serializeHasMany` method in your serializer.

Thanks to **@wycats** (as per discussion on github [#1273](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1273))

Something like

```
Deific.AppacitiveRESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    //primary key is '__id' in appacitive, overriding default behaviour
    primaryKey: '__id',

    serializeHasMany: function(record, json, relationship) {
        var key = relationship.key;

        var relationshipType = DS.RelationshipChange.determineRelationshipType(record.constructor, relationship);

        if (relationshipType === 'manyToNone' || relationshipType === 'manyToMany' || relationshipType === 'manyToOne') {
            json[key] = record.get(key).mapBy('id');
        // TODO support for polymorphic manyToNone and manyToMany relationships
        }
    }
});

Deific.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        namespace: 'service',
        defaultSerializer: 'Deific/appacitiveREST'
    }),
});
```

For time being this can be used. Hope this helps.

Comment: Amar, this seems to work ! Not sure that this is the only code change needed ... on my test environment I see that the related records (in my case a comment on a post) disappear for a few msec and then immediately reappear ... They disappear during the period I save the master record (thus the post in my case).  Will you inform the Ember Data team about your findings ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Ember Data: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1228

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should be fixed now.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1257

Comment: Is indeed solved, but still other issues with belongsTo relationship (e.g. changing a relationship does not set isDirty flag).  Will do a detailed test.