# How to set the value of a relationship in an ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember-data (1.0.0.beta2) application in which a model (A) has several 'belongsTo' relationships (with B, C and D).

The existing a's are shown in a template that also contains a button to create a new A. When the user clicks this button, a new A instance is created, and then instances of B, C, D are also created, and then they are linked.

My controller's code is something like this:

```
var a = this.get('store').createRecord(A, {});
var b = this.get('store').createRecord(A, {});
var c = this.get('store').createRecord(A, {});
var d = this.get('store').createRecord(A, {});
a.save().then(function(a_) {
  b.save().then(function(b_) {
    a_.set('b', b_);
    b_.set('a', a_);
    a_.save();
    b_.save();
    ...
  });    
});
```

The problem is: when 'a' is created, the template showing the list of existings a's is updated. However, this list uses information from a's parameter 'b' (of type B). But when a is updated by linking it to the object b, the list is not updated. Therefore, the list is displayed with incomplete information.

If I reload the page, or go to a different route and back to the list, then it is shown correctly.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Regardless of whether the code above is the proper way of setting up the new objects, the problem seems to be related with a bug in ember-data. Check:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703867/ember-data-save-loses-belongsto-relationship


After updating to the newest canary release of ember-data, my problem has been solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this PR addressed the issue : https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1257