# ember-data one to many relationship with EmbeddedRecordsMixin not saving the single record on create

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

I have two models organization and site as below:

site:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...,
  organization: DS.belongsTo('organization',{async:true}),
  administration: DS.attr('boolean',{defaultValue: false}),
  users: DS.hasMany('user',{async:true}),
  totalUsers: function() {
    return this.get('users').get('length');
  }.property('users.@each')
});
```

organization:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...,
  sites: DS.hasMany('site',{async:true}),
  totalSites: function() {
    return this.get('sites').get('length');
  }.property('sites.@each'),
  type: DS.attr('string')
});
```

each organization has many sites, but the sites have one organization.  I had previously used the an application serializer as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703867/ember-data-save-loses-belongsto-relationship/18739320#18739320), but it stopped working with ember-data 1.0.0 beta 10.  So I moved to the embeddedrecords mixin and seperate serializers like below

organization serializer:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    sites: {serialize: 'ids', deserialize: 'ids'}
  }
});
```

Then on the controller I am able to create the new site record and also push the new site record into the organization, but my problem is that the organization is not being saved into the original site record.  My new site controller action is below:

```
  actions: {
    addSite: function() {
      var self = this;
      var newSite = this.store.createRecord('site', {
        name: this.get('name'),
        abbreviation: this.get('abbreviation'),
        address: this.get('address'),
        city: this.get('city'),
        state: this.get('state'),
        postalcode: this.get('postalcode'),
        country: this.get('country'),
        phone: this.get('phone'),
        mingrade: this.get('mingrade'),
        maxgrade: this.get('maxgrade'),
        organization: self.get('selectedOrg'),
        administration: this.get('administration')
      });
      newSite.save().then(function(ns) {
        self.get('selectedOrg.sites').then(function() {
          self.get('selectedOrg.sites').addObject(ns).then(function() {
            self.get('selectedOrg').save().then(function() {
              self.transitionToRoute('site', ns);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

What could be causing the organization not to save, I know the data is there?  If I change the belongsTo on organization from async to not, it saves, but causes problems with lookups elsewhere in the app.  What can I do get this to save while also being async as well.  Do I need to add something else to the site serializer maybe?  I've tried adding in an organization attr to that serializer and nothing seems to change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`addObject` doesn't return a promise, your code is likely blowing up when you try and chain a then on it.

```
self.get('selectedOrg.sites').then(function() {
  self.get('selectedOrg.sites').addObject(ns).then(function() {
    self.get('selectedOrg').save().then(function() {
      self.transitionToRoute('site', ns);
    });
  });
});
```

Try something like this:

```
var selectedOrg = self.get('selectedOrg');
selectedOrg.get('sites').then(function(sites) {
  sites.addObject(ns);
  selectedOrg.save().then(function() {
    self.transitionToRoute('site', ns);    
  });
});
```

`selectedOrg` already has an ID, correct? If not, you're likely running into this issue: [github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542#issuecomment-56237770](http://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542#issuecomment-56237770). But since you're setting it on creation it should work with canary builds of Ember Data.

If selectedOrg doesn't have an ID, you'd need to save it first.

Comment: That is actually the part that is working right now.  I swapped your code in and it works both ways.  My problem is right above that.  In the newSite, it is not saving in the organization into the site record.  I can't figure out why that isn't working.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question.  selectedOrg already has an ID, correct?  If not, you're likely running into this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542#issuecomment-56237770.  But since you're setting it on creation it should work with canary builds of Ember Data.  If selectedOrg doesn't have an ID, you'd need to save it first.

Comment: selectedOrg does have an ID.  You were correct, it is the issue you have linked.  Running 1.0.0-beta.11+canary.4e51ded433 does resolve the issue, thank you again for your help.